UICollectionView dissapears when embedded into UIScrollView
So I have a weird problem:
I'm building infinite carausel (UICollectionView) that needs to be in vertical UIScrollView.
When I try to embed UICollectionView with a horizontal scroll into a vertical scrollview when I start scrolling vertically, UICollectionView dissapears. This is simplified code of my component:
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    private var contentView: UIStackView!
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var items = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green]
    private var currentIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupScrollView()
        setupCollectionView()
    }
    
    private func setupScrollView() {
        
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        contentView = UIStackView()
        contentView.axis = .vertical
        contentView.alignment = .center
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.greaterThanOrEqualToSuperview()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    private func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
        horizontalStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(collectionView.snp.bottom).offset(20)
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-20) // Ensure the stack view is within scroll view bounds
        }
        
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        
        // Initialize starting position
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.items.count * 10, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count * 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CarouselCell
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = items[indexPath.item % items.count]
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.bounds.size
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard scrollView = collectionView as? UICollectionView else { return }
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
        
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(items.count * 20)
        
        let pageIndex = Int(currentPage) % items.count
        currentIndex = pageIndex
        
        if currentPage < 1 {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (numberOfItems + currentPage), y: 0), animated: false)
        } else if currentPage >= numberOfItems {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (currentPage - numberOfItems), y: 0), animated: false)
        }
    }
}

// Custom UICollectionViewCell
class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "CarouselCell"
    
    let cardView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(cardView)
        
        // Add padding and set constraints for the cardView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Add any additional logic for the vertical scroll view if needed
    }
}

Everything works fine if I remove scrollView but still I need its functionality. Please help.

The collection view is "disappearing" because you are setting its .contentOffset based on the scrollView ...
Change your scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to only manipulate the collection view if it is triggering that delegate function:
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView == collectionView {
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
        
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(items.count * 20)
        
        let pageIndex = Int(currentPage) % items.count
        currentIndex = pageIndex
        
        if currentPage < 1 {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (numberOfItems + currentPage), y: 0), animated: false)
        } else if currentPage >= numberOfItems {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (currentPage - numberOfItems), y: 0), animated: false)
        }
    }
}


Edit
The change you made:
guard scrollView = collectionView as? UICollectionView else { return }

is attempting to assign collectionView to scrollView, instead of comparing them.
If you want to use a guard instead of an if, it should be this:
guard scrollView == collectionView else { return }


Here is your complete code. Take a good look at the changes I made to your SnapKit constraints... you were doing a number of things incorrectly:
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    private var contentView: UIStackView!
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var items = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green]
    private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupScrollView()
        setupCollectionView()
        
        // let's use some background colors, so we can
        //  see the frames of our UI elements
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
    private func setupScrollView() {
        
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
        
        contentView = UIStackView()
        contentView.axis = .vertical
        contentView.alignment = .center
        contentView.spacing = 12.0
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.bottom.equalTo(scrollView.contentLayoutGuide)
            make.width.equalTo(scrollView.frameLayoutGuide)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        
        let horizontalStackView = UIStackView()
        horizontalStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
        horizontalStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8)
        }
        for i in 0..<4 {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).square.fill") {
                let v = UIImageView(image: img)
                v.tintColor = .systemGreen
                horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
                v.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                    make.height.width.equalTo(40.0)
                }
            }
        }

        // let's add a bunch of views to the content stack view,
        //  so we will have vertical scrolling
        for _ in 0..<8 {
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBrown
            contentView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            v.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.9)
                make.height.equalTo(120.0)
            }
        }

        // Initialize starting position
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.items.count * 10, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count * 20
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CarouselCell
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = items[indexPath.item % items.count]
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.bounds.size
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard scrollView == collectionView else { return }
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        let currentPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
        
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(items.count * 20)
        
        let pageIndex = Int(currentPage) % items.count
        currentIndex = pageIndex
        
        if currentPage < 1 {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (numberOfItems + currentPage), y: 0), animated: false)
        } else if currentPage >= numberOfItems {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * (currentPage - numberOfItems), y: 0), animated: false)
        }
    }
}

// Custom UICollectionViewCell
class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CarouselCell"
    
    let cardView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(cardView)
        
        // Add padding and set constraints for the cardView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            cardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Add any additional logic for the vertical scroll view if needed
    }
}


Sorry I've copied code poorly, here. I have guard check which looks if scrollView is collectionView but this doesn't help. I think it's due to view hierarchy or something related to UIScrollView delegate because my UICollectionView draws first time and then when I start vertical scroll it dissapears. I can see from stacktrace that something is calling UICollectionView to reload but I cannot see in the code why and when (I have only one reload for this UICV). View stack looks somehow like this: VC -> UIScrollView -> UIStackView -> UICollectionView + other items.

@KristijanDelivuk - see the Edit to my answer.

Yea you're right. I've forgot about contentLayoutGuide and frameLayoutGuide. Didn't use ScrollView for years so that was crucial info. Now it works flawless. Thank you for your help! :)
